# Serilog - logstash index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, serilog

I am sending log messages (UDP) to logstash via serilog.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.UDPSink("host", port)
.MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
.CreateLogger();
```

But I would like to specify name on the logstash index. Any idea how?

Comment: Add your logstash configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know how your logstash config looks like, so I can't give you a **full** answer.
But, in general your `logStash.config` file should look like:

```
input {
     udp {
       port => ...
       id => "my_plugin_id"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        index => "%{your_defined_index}"
    }
}
```